# I can't install react native cli?

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native, command-prompt, react-native-cli

I'm using Window. I ran the following command in a node.js command prompt

npm install -g react-native-cli

It shows what is in the image.

[Node.js command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyfzW.png)

Anyone can tell me what's wrong? Have I downloaded the react native cli?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, there wasn't an error message...

Comment: Write the error given please

Comment: Nothing wrong with your screenshot. You can verify globally installed packages with `npm ls -g --depth=0`.

Comment: That means everything is right, but how do I know I have installed react native cli ?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link for installation and comment the error message you receive

https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-on-windows-90d85a72ae65#.rlkiklwkn

Comment: The link works just fine on my side. Can you provide your errors, so that we can see it and help if we can ?

Comment: please place the important contents of the link here. in case the link goes down